# using a d3 axis using a time scale, how do you evenly space wide gaps in time

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

This is for a multiline chart.

I'm displaying 20 points but in between them you might have a gap of days or weeks.  This causes the axis to bump the points left and right when looking at a gap of three weeks.  in general the points will be hourly, but long gaps may occur.  I tried using d3.svg.axis.tickValues to set the values but it still spaces them unevenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a scale

`d3.scale.linear().domain([..]).range([...]);`

More info here : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales